# Как override-нуть страницу "Ваш аккаунт был создан"

Tags: html, yii2

После регистрации yii2 немного магичит, в итоге чего происходит переход на эту страницу

[image: введите сюда описание изображения] *Ваш аккаунт был создан*

В которой не очень красиво сделано объявление:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Оно прилипло к верху экрана, ну в данном случае, к навбару. В нем нет кнопок популярных почтовых сервисов. И бесит какой-то странный знак с вопросом под объявлением.

Понятное дело, что мне его захотелось переделать под свой вкус, но, полазив в вендоре и своих файлах, я не нашел этой страницы (Мб плохо искал)

Все что я нашел - контроллер, который перенаправляет меня сюда

```
    if ($model->load(\Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->register()) {
        return $this->render('/message', [
            'title'  => \Yii::t('user', 'Your account has been created'),
            'module' => $this->module,
        ]);
    }
```

Вижу, что тут есть какой-то `$this->module`, который видимо отвечает за саму страницу. Но как мне заменить ее на свой `html` файл?